# Filter JSON without lambda symbol

Tags: jquery, json

Hi I am trying to filter the JSON where qty cannot be empty. So I have created the filter method -

```
payloadU.payload.keyData.forEach(e => e.products = e.products.filter(p => p.qty))
```

But the Internet Explorer is giving me syntax error due to lambda symbols `=>`.
Can you please suggest another way to write without the lambda symbol?

Comment: If this is a serious project, integrate Babel into your build process and transpile to ES5 automatically

Comment: it's called Arrow function and it's part of ES6 specification. You need to use anonymous function for IE

Comment: Alternatively don't use arrow functions which don't have cross browser support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
payloadU.payload.keyData.forEach(function (e) {
  return e.products = e.products.filter(function (p) {
      return p.qty;
  });
});
```